# How to search my PDF with grep?

Tags: pdf, grep, pdftotext

I have followed ideas from this thread but it does not work.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/how-can-i-grep-in-pdf-files

```
 pdftotext PercivalWalden.pdf - | grep 'Slepian'
 pdftotext PercivalWalden.pdf - | grep 'Naive'
 pdftotext PercivalWalden.pdf - | grep 'Filter'
```

I know for sure that 'Filter' appears at least 100 times in this book.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Tordek: please be so awesome and undelete the answer you've deleted. Your comment below the deletion is inappropriate: because you overlooked that this answer was from the OP asker, who tried to answer his own question (who obviously is handicapped by not being a good native English speaker). Instead of deleting it, you could have shown a more neighbourly attitude by improving its English language.

Comment: I'm sorry, @KurtPfeifle, but I deleted it because it is not an answer, not because of OP's mastery of english; it is a comment regarding the original question, and as such should be a comment or an edit.

Comment: @Tordek: thanks for un-deleting anyway. It may not be a real answer, but it explains that the problem wasn't "real" either. And such a thing may happen to a lot of other users and even developers (I've seen it before, which is why I was able to answer it...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *really* can grep a given string (that you can 'see' and read on a rendered or printed PDF page) from a PDF, even with the help of `pdftotext`, then you must be very lucky indeed.

First off: most of the advice from the link you provided to `unix.stackexchange.com` is very uninformed (to put it most politely). Most of the answers there are clearly written by people who are not familiar with the huge range of PDF variations out there.

In your case, you are trying to convert the file with the help of `pdftotext` first, streaming the output to *stdout*.

There are many types of PDF where `pdftotext` cannot extract the text at all. The reasons for this may be (listings below not complete):

1. The "text" that you see is not based on using a font. It may be one big raster image generated by a scan or other production process, then embedded into a PDF file shell. This may make the page only *appear* to be text strings.
2. The "text" that you see is not based on using a font. It may be a series of small vector drawings (or small raster images), that only *look* like text strings to our eyes and brain.

   There are many software applications, which do convert fonts to so-called *'outlines'*. The reason for this seemingly strange behaviour may be:

   - Circumvent licensing problems (when a certain font disallows its embedding).
   - Impose a handicap upon attempts to extract the text.
   - Accidentally wrong setting in the PDF generating application.
3. The font is embedded as a *subset* in the PDF file (by the PDF generating software -- users usually do not have much control over the details of this operation) and uses a 'custom' encoding, but the file does not provide a `toUnicode` table to map the *glyphs* to *characters*.

   'Glyphs' are the well-defined *shapes* in each font drawn on screen. Glyphs map to characters for the computer  -- our eyes merely *see* these shapes and our brains translate these to characters without needing a `toUnicode` table. Programs like `pdftotext` require a `toUnicode` table to reverse the translation of glyphs back to characters.

---

You can use a command line utility named `pdffonts` to gain a first insight into the fonts used by your PDF file. ***Example output:***

```
pdffonts paper-projectiris---final.pdf 

 name                       type         encoding       emb sub uni object ID
 -------------------------- ------------ -------------- --- --- --- ---------
 TCQJEF+CMCSC10             Type 1       Builtin        yes yes no      96  0
 VPAFLY+CMBX12              Type 1       Builtin        yes yes no      97  0
 CWAIXW+CMTI12              Type 1       Builtin        yes yes no      98  0
 OBMDLT+CMR12               Type 1       Builtin        yes yes no      99  0
```

In this case, text extraction (and your method of grepping for strings) should work:

- Even though the column named `uni` (telling if a `toUnicode` map is embedded in the PDF file)
  says `no` for each single font, the `encoding` column does not contain `custom`, but `builtin` (meaning that a glyph->character mapping is provided with the font file, which is of type `Type 1`.

---

***To sum it up:*** Without access to your PDF file it is impossible to tell why you cannot "grep" for the strings you are looking for!